# Blender partially rendering my scene

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to render a donut but when I render it in both Blender Render and Cycles Render I only get a grey/black portion of my scene rendered. By the way, I already checked if some of my objects are visible for rendering.

Result of rendering in both Rendering modes:

[image]

My scene:

[image]

Comment: Where is your camera?

Comment: http://imgur.com/B8oBXxp - here it is

Comment: @JOHNNYT If you need to add more information to your question please use the [edit] link below your question.

Comment: Your camera object is not set as active camera for the scene. Make it so either from the scene tab in the properties window or by selecting the camera and pressing Ctrl + 0

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! i'm new to Blender and i'm pretty confused with some options here .